# Clang doesn't seem to generate error for uninitialized class member integer

Tags: c++, clang

Is there a way to force Clang to warn/error about this uninitialized class member:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    size_t f()
    {
        return ++counter;
    }

    size_t counter;
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    std::cout << "value: " << (size_t)s.f() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using these flags but don't seem to get anything:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weverything
```

Tried the above on Godbolt with Clang 17

Comment: gcc warns with `-Wuninitialized` from `-O1` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qK9TGf1Go).

Comment: `-fsanitize=memory` catches this at runtime.

Comment: Are you using any optimization? If not, some potential errors will go unnoticed.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Even if I use `-O0` there's no warning

Comment: -O0 is no optimization. You may need -O1 or -O2.

Comment: Why do you expect a error here? It'd be nice to have some kind of warning but it's mostly well defined. The data member is default-initialized, it's just that means nothing for int

Comment: @TerenceSimpson Well-defined and desired behavior are at odds here. It is default-initialized, not zero-initialized.

Comment: So add the special incantation to make it work: `{}`, now it's value-initialized

Comment: @TerenceSimpson I expect a warning, which I've chosen to be promoted to an error. Just like what GCC apparently does.

Comment: "it's mostly well defined" That's an odd phrasing for radioactive. And in the OP program it is UB. Anyways, MSAN on clang and sometimes luck on gcc... See also https://clang.llvm.org/docs/analyzer/checkers.html#optin-cplusplus-uninitializedobject (although no personal experience with that one).

Comment: "I expect a warning" Warnings are not mandatory. Sometimes you get them, sometimes you don't. You cannot rely on the compiler catching all of your errors, but you can send a bug report to clang.